# any sample for state issuance->update->exit in corda

Tags: corda

I am working on the hello world sample for corda and am able to run issuance of state sample.
Is there any tutorial explaining how to do state update, like how to do input state and output state and initiate such flows.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the various sample CorDapps:

- You can find the official samples under github.com/corda/samples
- You can find the community samples under corda.net/develop/samples.html

These contain many examples of flows that consume states. The `obligation-cordapp` in the official samples repo is one such example.